# relationship between a finite moment and a polynomial tail

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, distribution-tails

I see condition (C2) in the paper http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~tcai/paper/Precision-Matrix.pdf
is called polynomial-type tails. I do not know why they call it as polynomial-type tails.

Let $X$ be a mean-zero random variable. The (C2) condition therein is $E|X|^p<C$ with some positive constants $p,C$.

I know that: if $E|X|^p<C$ with some positive constants $p,C$, then by Markov inequality we have
\begin{equation}
P(|X|\ge t)\le \frac{E|X|^p}{t^p}=Ct^{-p} \ \text{for all $t>0$}.
\end{equation}
So, a finite moment implies a polynomial tail.

Now my question is: If $P(|X|\ge t)\le Ct^{-p}$ for an constant $p$ and all $t>0$ (maybe $t\to \infty$?), does it have any finite moment?

Or could anyone explain why they call the condition (C2) as polynomial-type tails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(|X|>t) \sim t^{-p},$ then the PDF goes like (differentiate CDF) $f_X(x)\sim x^{-(p+1)},$ so has a power law tail. When you integrate to get $E(|X|^q)$ you have $\int^\infty x^qx^{-(p+1)}dx$ which converges for $q-p-1 < -1,$ i.e. $q <p$ and diverges for $q\ge p.$

Thus if you have a power law tail (I'd call it power law, not polynomial, but that's unimportant), it corresponds to a particular moment diverging... the faster the power law decays, the larger number of moments are finite. Whereas if the tail decays exponentially, all the moments are finite.

Comment: How convolution is related to the calculation of expectaion?

Comment: @Beginner I assume you were confused by the "*" in the integral? I just meant multiplication (and I don't know why I used that notation... it's bad and I fixed it).

Comment: Uh yes..... I was so confused, thank you for the update!

Comment: but the critical point is that the integral $\int_0^{\infty} x^s dx$ doesn't exist for any $s$.  so it seems that we are stuck. Did I mistake something?

Comment: I noticed that you didn't write lower limit of the integral $\int^{\infty}$, is there a reason?

Comment: @Beginner I assume that’s *why* I omitted the lower limit on the integral. We are discussing tail behavior. So it doesn’t matter that e.g. $\int_0^\infty 1/x^2dx$ diverges on the zero side… what matters is it converges on the infinity side.